# What goes wrong with this proof of Dirichlet's Theorem?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, invariant-theory

I am curious what goes wrong with this invariant theoretic argument of Dirichlet's Theorem of primes in arithmetic progression.  I know that something goes wrong, but I am really curious about what the proverbial "fly in the ointment" is.

Here is the argument.

Let $ S $ be the set of primes $ p $ such that $ p \not \equiv a \mod{n} $, and let $ p_{i} $ be the $ i $-th element of $ S $.  Define an action $ \beta $ of $ \mathbb{G}_{m} $ on $ \mathbb{A}^{N^{2}}_{\mathbb{C}} $ as follows.  If the affine coordinate ring of $ \mathbb{A}^{N^{2}}_{\mathbb{C}} $ is $ \mathbb{C}[x_{i,j}] $ where $ 1 \le i,j \le N $ and the affine coordinate ring of $ \mathbb{G}_{m} $ is $ \mathbb{C}[z]_{z} $, then let $ \beta^{\sharp}(x_{i,j})= z^{p_{i}-nj-a+1} x_{i,j} $.  An element $ x_{i,j} $ is a character of order one if and only if $ p_{i} =nj+a $.

Next we prove that the following three statements are equivalent.  The first statement is (1): the variety $ D(f(X)) $ is a trivial $ \mathbb{G}_{m} $-bundle, and $ \mathbb{G}_{m} $ acts freely on $ \mathbb{A}^{N^{2}}_{\mathbb{C}} $. The second statement is (2): there is a $ \mathbb{G}_{m} $-equivariant morphism $ \Phi: D(f(X)) \to \mathbb{G}_{m} $ and $ \mathbb{G}_{m} $ acts freely on $ \mathbb{A}^{N^{2}}_{\mathbb{C}} $.  The third statement is (3): there is a character $ g(X)/h(X) $ of order one, such that $ g(X) $ and $ h(X) $ have no common factor and all common factors of $ g(X) $ and $ h(X) $ are factors of $ f(X) $.

If (1) is true, then there is a $ \mathbb{G}_{m} $-equivariant isomorphism $ \lambda: D(f(X)) \to Y \times \mathbb{G}_{m} $ for a sub-variety $ Y $.  If $ p_{2} $ is the projection from $ Y \times \mathbb{G}_{m} \to \mathbb{G}_{m} $, then $ p_{2} \circ \lambda $ is the desired morphism $ \Phi: D(f(X)) \to \mathbb{G}_{m} $.  Therefore (1) implies (2).

If (2) holds, then let $ Y $ be the scheme theoretic pre-image of the identity with its reduced induced scheme structure.  The scheme $ Y $ is a variety.  Define a morphism $ \lambda: D(f(X)) \to Y \times \mathbb{G}_{m} $ via the morphism which sends $ x $ to $ (\Phi(x)^{-1} \ast x, \Phi(x)) $.  The morphism $ \lambda $ has an inverse, namely the one which sends $ (y,t) $ to $ t \ast y $.  We do not have to worry about issues with separability, so $ \lambda $ is an isomorphism which shows that (2) implies (1).

If (2) holds, then $ \Phi^{\sharp}(z) $ is equal to $ g(X)/h(X) $ where $ g(X)/h(X) $ is a unit in $ D(f(X)) $ and $ g(X), h(X) $ have no common factors.  As a result, all factors of $ g(X) $ and $ h(X) $ are factors of $ f(X) $.  Because $ \Phi $ is $ \mathbb{G}_{m} $-equivariant, if $ \mu_{\mathbb{G}_{m}} $ is the multiplication morphism of $ \mathbb{G}_{m} $ then the following computations show that $ g(X)/h(X) $ is a character of order one:
\begin{align*}
zg(X)/h(X)&= (\Phi^{\sharp} \otimes \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{C}[z]_{z}})(z \otimes z) \\
&= (\Phi^{\sharp} \otimes \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{C}[z]_{z}}) \circ \mu_{\mathbb{G}_{m}}^{\sharp}(z) \\
&= \beta^{\sharp} \circ \Phi^{\sharp}(z) \\
&= \beta^{\sharp}(g(X)/h(X)).
\end{align*}
As a result (2) implies (3).

If $ g(X), h(X) $ fulfill the requirements of (3), then let $ \Phi^{\sharp}(z) $ equal $ g(X)/h(X) $.  The ring homomorphism $ \Phi^{\sharp} $ determines a morphism $ \Phi: D(f(X)) \to D(z) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[z]) $.  The following computations show that it is $ \mathbb{G}_{m} $-equivariant,
\begin{align*}
\beta^{\sharp} \circ \Phi^{\sharp}(z) &= \beta^{\sharp}(g(X)/h(X))\\
&= z g(X)/h(X) \\
&= (\Phi^{\sharp} \otimes \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{C}[z]_{z}})(z \otimes z) \\
&= (\Phi^{\sharp} \otimes \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{C}[z]_{z}}) \circ \mu_{\mathbb{G}_{m}}^{\sharp}(z).
\end{align*}
As a result, (3) implies (2).

Let us assume that $ N $ is large enough so that there are at least four indeterminates $ x_{i,j} $ such that $  (i_{1},j_{1}), (i_{2},j_{2}), (i_{3},j_{3}), (i_{4},j_{4}) $ are distinct ordered pairs, $ \gcd(p_{i_{1}}-nj_{1}-a+1, p_{i_{2}}-nj_{2}-a+1)=1 $ and $ \gcd(p_{i_{3}}-nj_{3}-a+1, p_{i_{4}}-nj_{4}-a+1)=1 $.

Let $ V_{1} $ be the open sub-variety $ D(x_{i_{1},j_{1}}x_{i_{2},j_{2}}) $ and $ V_{2} $ be the open sub-variety $ D(x_{i_{3},j_{3}}x_{i_{4},j_{4}}) $.  Without loss of generality there are natural numbers $ a_{1},b_{1} $ such that if $ f_{1}(X) $ is equal to $ x_{i_{1},j_{1}}^{a_{1}}/x_{i_{2},j_{2}}^{b_{1}} $, then $ f_{1}(X) $ is a character of order one on $ V_{1} $.  Likewise, there are natural numbers $ a_{2},b_{2} $ such that if $ f_{2}(X) $ is equal to $ x_{i_{3},j_{3}}^{a_{2}}/x_{i_{4},j_{4}}^{b_{2}} $, then $ f_{2}(X) $ is a character of order one on $ V_{2} $.

If $ u(X) $ is equal to $ f_{2}(X)/f_{1}(X) $, then $ u(X) $ is a unit on $ V_{1} \cap V_{2} $.  As a result, the endomorphism of the affine coordinate ring of $ V_{1} \cap V_{2} $ which multiplies a function by $ u(X) $ is an isomorphism of the affine coordinate ring of $ V_{1} \cap V_{2} $.  Therefore we obtain an isomorphism of the affine variety $ V_{1} \cap V_{2} $, which we shall denote by $ u(X)^{\ast} $.

If $ \iota_{1}: V_{1} \cap V_{2} \to V_{1} $ (respectively $ \iota_{2}: V_{1} \cap V_{2} \to V_{2} $) is the typical embedding of $ V_{1} \cap V_{2} $ into $ V_{1} $ (respectively $ V_{2} $), then embed $ V_{1} \cap V_{2} $ into $ V_{1} $ via $ \iota_{1} \circ u(X)^{\ast} $ and $ V_{1} \cap V_{2} $ into $ V_{2} $ via $ \iota_{2} $.  With these embeddings it is possible to glue $ V_{1} \cup V_{2} $ into a variety which is isomorphic to the typical scheme theoretic union of $ V_{1} $ and $ V_{2} $.

Now if $ \Phi_{1}: V_{1} \to \mathbb{G}_{m} $ is the $ \mathbb{G}_{m} $-equivariant morphism which is obtained from the ring homomorphism which sends $ z $ to $ f_{1}(X) $ and $ \Phi_{2}: V_{2} \to \mathbb{G}_{m} $ is the $ \mathbb{G}_{m} $-equivariant morphism which is obtained from the ring homomorphism which sends $ z $ to $ f_{2}(X) $, then $ \Phi_{1} $ and $ \Phi_{2} $ glue together to form a morphism $ \Phi: V_{1} \cup V_{2} \to \mathbb{G}_{m} $.  If $ \Phi^{\sharp} $ is the corresponding ring homomorphism, then $ \Phi^{\sharp}(z) \in k[x_{i,j}]_{1 \le i,j \le N} $.  From (3) with respect to $ \mathbb{A}^{N^{2}}_{\mathbb{C}} $ as a whole, we know that if $ \Phi^{\sharp}(z) $ is equal to $ f(X) $, then $ f(X) $ is a character of order one.

If $ f(X) $ is a polynomial which is a character of order one, then each monomial must be a character of order one.  If $ X^{J} $ is a monomial, which is a character of order one, then there is a unique indeterminate $ x_{i,j} $ dividing $ X^{J} $ which is a character of order one. A linear indeterminate $ x_{i,j} $ is a character of order one if and only if $ p_{i}=nj+a $, which implies that the set of primes congruent to $ a $ modulo $ n $ is infinite.

This argument is too good to be true because for any function $ f(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}): \mathbb{Z}^{n} \to \mathbb{Z} $ this argument says that if there are four distinct values $ (X_{1},X_{2},X_{3},X_{4}) $ such that $ \gcd(f(X_{1}), f(X_{2}))=1 $ and $ \gcd(f(X_{3}),f(X_{4}))=1 $, then there are infinitely many tuples $ X_{i} $ such that $ f(X_{i}) $ is equal to one.  This clearly cannot hold, so there is something wrong with this argument.  What is it?

Comment: This might be a lot clearer and more inviting if you dropped all mention of primes and Dirichlet and simply presented your (necessarily incorrect) "proof" of the false statement in the last paragraph. Better yet, restrict yourself to one particular counterexample $f$.

Comment: Of course in the process of rewriting as I've suggested, your error might jump out at you.

Comment: I realized the error and I am writing the answer.  Thank you for reminding me @StevenLandsburg.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that the global sections of $ V_{1} \cup V_{2} $ are isomorphic to $ \mathbb{C}[X] $ if the open sub-variety $ V_{1} \cap V_{2} $ is embedded into $ V_{1} $ via $ \iota_{1} $ and $ V_{2} $ via $ \iota_{2} $.  However, because the embedding of $ V_{1} \cap V_{2} $ into $ V_{1} $ is via $ \iota_{1} \circ u(X)^{\ast} $, the global sections of $ V_{1} \cup V_{2} $ are polynomial multiples of $ u(X) $.  A necessary part of the p(r)oof is that there is a polynomial which is a character of order one.